# The right derivative of a convex function $f$ is right continuous $\iff$ $f$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, convex-analysis

Let be $f$ a convex function defined on an open set. We know from theory that $f'_{+},f'_{-}$ both exist not decreasing.

**Claim :** The right derivative of a convex function $f$ is right continuous $\iff$ $f$ is differentiable.

I think $[\Leftarrow]$ follows directly from definition because if $f'$ exists, both left and right limits exist finite and has to be coincident $f'_{+} = f'_{-} = l \in \mathbb{R}$ so $f'_{+}$ is continuous.

I'm stuck with $[\Rightarrow]$. I was unable to approach the problem by any angle.

Any help, hint or solution would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your proof about $\Leftarrow$ is not clear...see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1757987/how-to-prove-that-the-right-derivative-of-a-convex-function-is-right-continuous?rq=1

Comment: Yes i see, thanks you're right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Let $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=x$ for $x \geq 0$. Then $f'(x+)$ is right continuous but $f$ is  not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful, i should have looked for a conterexample