# Does local convexity imply global convexity around a minimum?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, convexity-inequality

This is a follow-up of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3724637/is-there-a-global-convexity-locally-around-a-minimum).

Let $F:(0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function satisfying $F(1)=0$, which is strictly increasing on $[1,\infty)$, and strictly decreasing on $(0,1]$.

Suppose also that $F|_{(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)}$ is convex and smooth for some $\epsilon>0$.

> **Question:** Is it true that $F$ is convex at **at every point** $y \in (1-\epsilon,1)$?

By convexity at a point $y$, I mean that that for any $x_1,x_2>0, \alpha \in [0,1]$ satisfying $\alpha x_1 + (1- \alpha)x_2 =y$, we have
$$
F(y)=F\left(\alpha x_1 + (1- \alpha)x_2 \right) \leq \alpha F(x_1) + (1-\alpha)F(x_2). \tag{1}
$$
[Equivalently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734910/does-convexity-around-a-point-imply-the-function-is-above-the-tangent-at-that-po), $F$ is above its tangent at $(y,F(y))$:
$$
F(x) \ge F(y)+F'(y) (x-y) \tag{2}
$$
for every $x \in (0,\infty)$.

> I know that [there exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3747108/104576) a $\delta>0$ such that $F$ is convex **at every point** $y \in (1-\delta,1)$. The question is whether we can take $\delta=\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexamples can be given. Suppose $F$ can be continuously extended to $0$ and the property holds. Let $x_n\to0$ and let $t_n= \frac{y-x_n}{1-x_n}$ so that $(1-t_n)x_n + t_n1=y$. As $n\to\infty$ you get that
$$(1-t_n)F(x_n)+t_nF(1)=(1-t_n)F(x_n)\to (1-y) F(0)$$
by assumption each term is $≥F(y)$, hence the limit also is larger than $F(y)$ and you get that
$$F(0)≥\frac{F(y)}{1-y}$$
must necessarily hold. But by choosing $F(x)=(x-1)^2$ on $[\frac12,\infty)$ and then extending smoothly and monotonously on $[0,\frac12]$ so that $F(0)=\frac38$ you find that all conditions are fufilled but the necessary condition derived above fails for $y=\frac12$. This basic idea can be applied also if you are interested in $F$ being divergent at $0$.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very cool example. Do you really think that an analogous idea should work for $F$ which is divergent at $0$?

Comment: Yes, you can get an analogous inequality for the value of something like $F(1/2)$, then let  $F$ be quadratic on $[3/4,\infty)$ and modify $F$ suitably from $3/4$ to $1/2$ so that the inequality is violated. To the left of $1/2$ let $F$ diverge. Using $0$ and $1$ just makes the inequality look pleasing.

Comment: Alternatively note that if you rescale the argument of a convex thing it remains convex, and if you translate the argument it will also remain convex. So extend the $F$ above to $-1$ so that it diverges at $-1$ and then let $\tilde F(x) := F( \frac12 x + \frac12)$, which now diverges at $0$, satisfies the requirements but fails to be convex at $y=3/4$.